# Using Python modules based on a condition

Tags: python, import, module

I want to import modules dynamically in my class depending on some conditions.

```
    class Test(object):
        def __init__ (self,condition):
            if condition:
                import module1 as mymodule
            else:
                import module2 as mymodule

            self.mymodule = mymodule

        def doTest(self):
            self.mymodule.doMyTest
```

where module1 and module2 implement doMyTest in different way.

Calling it as

```
    mytest1 = Test(true)  # Use module1
    mytest2.doTest()

    mytest2 = Test(false)  # Use module2
    mytest2.doTest()
```

This works but is there possibly a more idiomatic way?  Are there any possible problems?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't really work _quite_ as well as you think it does… but that's about what the import statements do globally and locally, and has nothing to do with the condition stuff.

Comment: there *might* be a more idiomatic way depending on the actual nature of the condition you're checking.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to develop a test suite where the actual implementation of the test methods may differ, depending in which category tested object falls.

Comment: @abarnert can you please give more info or point to some resources, why this construction possesses a problem?

Comment: @peterk: It's not really a problem, so much as possibly non-obvious behavior. The import table is global. So, `module1` will only be executed the first time you `import module1 as mymodule`; after that, each subsequent `import module1 as mymodule` is effectively equivalent to `mymodule = sys.modules['module1']`. So, it might be less misleading to make that explicit: import `module1` and `module2` once, then just have `if…: self.mymodule = module1… else: self.mymodule = module2`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course normally you don't want to import modules in the middle of an `__init__` method, but a testing class is an obvious exception to that rule, so let's ignore that part and imagine you were doing this at top level:

```
if test_c_implementation:
    import c_mymodule as mymodule
else:
    import py_mymodule as mymodule
```

That's perfectly idiomatic. In fact, you see code like that in the stdlib and other code written by core developers.

Except in the very-common [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/3.3/glossary.html#term-eafp) cases, where the condition is just there to avoid an exception, in which case it's more idiomatic to just do this:

```
try:
    import lxml.etree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
```

Comment: Thank you.  In my case the import can be placed in other Test method, not __init__.  I am more interested whether passing the module reference as a Test attribute is a valid Python technique.

Comment: @peterk: It wasn't so much about the `__init__` as about doing it in _any_ method. And the point is: that's an odd thing to do; the only obvious use for that is in a test library… which is exactly what you're writing, so it doesn't matter that it's odd.

Comment: @peterk: Anyway, a module is a first-class value, just a namespace like any other, so it's certainly _valid_ to pass one around, store it as an attribute, etc. Most modules aren't really designed to be _thought of_ as values, but there are definitely reasonable exceptions (even in the stdlib, `random` has the exact same API as a `random.Random` instance), and again, it may easily be reasonable for a test library to think of a module as a value even if normal users of the module wouldn't.